# Apresentar consulta na mesma pagina da form

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web de um serviço de "Corridas Compartilhadas" (tipo Uber), onde quero que uma consulta por CPF seja apresentada no card verde. Quero que quando eu consulte o CPF, apresente no card verde, sem sair da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Script do form:

```
    <form id="cons_motoca" action="componentes/cons_motoca.php" method="POST">
        <div class="input-field col s10">
            <input placeholder="Busca por CPF" name="cpf" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2 ">
            <button class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light " type="submit" name="consulta-completa"><i class="material-icons">search</i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Script da consulta ao banco:

```
<div>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['cpf'])){
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>NOME</th>";
                echo "<th>DISPONIBILIDADE</th>";
                echo "<th>CARRO</th>";
                echo "<th>CPF</th>";
                echo "<th>DATA DE NASCIMENTO</th>";
                echo "<th>SEXO</th>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
            mysqli_select_db($strcon, 'uber');
            $sql = "SELECT nome, disponibilidade, carro, cpf, nascimento, sexo FROM tb_motorista WHERE cpf = $_POST[cpf]";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao retornar dados");

            while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                $nome = $registro['nome'];
                $disponibilidade = $registro['disponibilidade'];
                $carro = $registro['carro'];
                $cpf = $registro['cpf'];
                $nascimento = $registro['nascimento'];
                $sexo = $registro['sexo'];
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$nome."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$disponibilidade."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$carro."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$cpf."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$nascimento."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$sexo."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            mysqli_close($strcon);
        echo "</table>";

    } else {
        echo 'Digite o CPF de um Motorista para realizar uma consulta';
    }
?>
```

Comment: pesquisa sobre AJAX

Comment: Tente com o [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
No link oficial já tem uns exemplos

Comment: Você pode utilizar o ajax ou axios para fazer a requisição de forma assíncrona. Eu inclusive prefiro o axios (https://github.com/axios/axios).